# Three-letter acronyms (TLAs)

Tags: computer-building

I'm a developer and know a good number of TLAs, but is there a definitive place to look for computer TLAs?  I have wanted to build a computer from parts, but come mainly from a computer software background.  When I try to read online on how to go about it, sometimes it is easy to get lost in all the jargon.

Also, what about TLAs having different meanings in different contexts?

Comment: you're missing out on lots of fun by limiting yourself to three letters.  GUID, ASCII, EBDIC, SATA, SDRAM....  heck, there's your primary and secondary storage right there -- you can't build a computer these days with just TLAs.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Acronym Finder](http://acronymfinder.com/) a good source of information. It lists all the possibilities and also categorises them.

*(Though this question is on the borderline of what's allowed here. It's not strictly computer related and therefore falls foul of the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq))*

Comment: i wondered about that too, but it boils down to a question about references for computer jargon, so i'm kinda ok with it.  it might be the one question where "Google it!" is an acceptable and correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this site?

> http://www.akhphd.au.dk/~bertho/tla/tlaindex.html

And although not specific to computers, there's also Wikipedia's lists of TLA's:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_TLAs